# Usage of In and Within difference

Tags: prepositions, ambiguity, sentence-meaning

This has been asked before but I didn't understand. I am no English student, but can someone explain how these two statements could mean different things?

> Xylem and Phloem ***within*** a vascular bundle are arranged in an alternate manner.

> Xylem and Phloem ***in*** a vascular bundle are arranged in an alternate manner.

I think they mean the same but my biology book says they're different. I'm not asking which of the statements is correct, only the difference.

Comment: How does your biology book suggest that they are different?

Comment: Clothes can be in a bundle but might not have a mouse within it.

Comment: @KateBunting my book only says that the first statement is correct and second statement is less correct. The reason it states:

'although both statements seem to be similar use of "within" and "in" cannot be used interchangeably in every context.'

Comment: How does the book say they are different? Have you told us that? Is your book a biology book or a book on learning scientific/science English?

Comment: It seems strange for a biology book to be discussing the meanings of non-biological words. However - if things are 'in a bundle' they are gathered together. If something is _within_ a bundle, it is enclosed inside that bundle.

Comment: @KateBunting vascular bundle is used in biology.

Comment: @Lambie - I know what a vascular bundle is. I was just surprised that a biology textbook should be concerning itself with whether _in_ and _within_ are interchangeable.

Comment: @KateBunting There are textbooks by profession: legal, scientific, etc. Cambridge English for Scientists, for example. The only reason I know this is because I used several books for teaching legal English.

Comment: There was a past year exam question where there were 4 statements, and we had to choose the incorrect statement (when all statements are correct/incorrect we are to choose the most appropriate-this is given on the first page of the test). The second statement that I have quoted was the answer. The first statement is written in the main biology textbook that we use. But our extra module was giving the explanation for the choice of the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xylem and Phloem within a vascular bundle are arranged in an alternate manner.

Xylem and Phloem in a vascular bundle are arranged in an alternate manner.

The distinction is this:
The first means that xylem and phloem are **inside the bundle**. inside can be said within.

The second means that they are arranged or ordered in a bundle, which does not mean inside it or within it.

The clothes were *in a bundle*, and there was *a mouse inside it aka within it*.

Answer (score 0):

Kate has stated the major distinction. Here, we consider only the prepositional usages, and avoid less central metaphorical usages.

'Within' demands enclosure in a container (literal or metaphorical), and the container (italicised in the examples below) is usually distinct from the items within.

- within *a goldfish bowl* (literal, locative usage)

> a: before the end of
>
> - gone within *a week* b: (1): not beyond the quantity, degree, or limitations of
> - live within *your income* [your available money]
>
> (2): in or into the scope or sphere of within the *jurisdiction of the
> state*
>
> (3): in or into *the range of*
>
> within reach
>
> within sight
>
> (4) — used as a function word to indicate a specified difference or
> margin came within two points of a perfect mark
>
> within *a mile of* the town [within an area reaching a mile out from
> the  town]

[[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/within)]

.......

'In' can imply a container *or* just the assemblage itself:

- in a goldfish bowl
- in a jumbled mass

Comment: within the bundle is not enclosure in a container.

Comment: Notionally, it is. 'A bundle of newspapers was lying on the porch'. Not 'were', even for those seeing notional agreement as the better approach. 'Metaphorical', line 3.